# Setting max width bigger than parent in absolute positioned child doesn't work when parent is positioned relatively

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a basic navigation  bar where a child dropdown appears when hovering over a list item. I want to position this dropdown starting at the right most edge of the list item I am hovering over, but I want it this dropdown be able to scale bigger than the list item you're hovering over.

The trouble is that when I position the parent relative, the dropdown's width is constricted to the width of the list item you're hovering over, when I remove postion relative I lose the ability to position it the way I want it.

When the parent List item doesn't have position relative it looks like this:
[image: Situation where parent does not have position relative]

But I want the right edge of that dropdown to align with the right side of the list item I'm hovering on. When I add position relative to the list items, the width of the dropdown is contsrained like this:
[image]

The markup looks like follows:

```
<nav>
<ul class="outer-list">
    <li>
        <a>
            Work
        </a>
        <ul class="inner-list">
            <li>Sub1</li>
            <li>Sub2</li>
            <li>Sub3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="outer-list">
    <li>
        <a>
            Contact
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="outer-list">
    <li>
        <a>
            Helpdesk
        </a>
        <ul class="inner-list">
            <li>Sub1</li>
            <li>Sub2</li>
            <li>Sub3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="outer-list">
    <li>
        <a>
            Subscriptions
        </a>
        <ul class="inner-list">
            <li>Sub1</li>
            <li>Sub2</li>
            <li>Sub3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I am not in charge of the markup, but if it needs to change to allow for a solution that is fine.

My CSS is as follows:

```
.outer-list{
        .dropdown{
            padding-right: 20px;
            a{
                color: black;
                text-decoration: none;
                position: relative;
                .icon-dropdown{
                    position: absolute;
                    display: inline-block;
                    width: 6px;
                    height: 4px;
                    background-image: url('./Assets/BlueArrowIcon.svg');
                    background-size: cover;
                    background-position: center;
                    top: 50%;
                    right: -11px;
                    transform: translateY(-50%)
                }
            }
            .inner-list{
                padding: 25px 20px;
                display: none;
                position: absolute;
                background-color: $color-white;
                box-shadow: 5px 0px 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.16);
                z-index: 1;
                max-width: 310px;
                li{
                    margin-bottom: 20px;
                    &:hover{
                        a{
                            color: $color-dark-red;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            &:hover{
                a{
                    color: $color-blue;
                }
                .inner-list{
                    display: block;
                    a{
                        color: black;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        &:last-of-type{
            .dropdown{
                padding-right: 0px;
            }
        }
    }
```

If anyone could help me that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just position the sub list to the right and make sure the text does not break with `white-space:nowrap`. That should do it.

Comment: I would still like the words of the subitems to wrap once they would make the ul surpass 310px, is there another way to d this?